# VB.NET UI Automation SetValue Operation Time Out Error

Tags: vb.net, ui-automation

On a automation based project i am using following code to automate another application. It was working fine before, but now it's shows "Operation Time Out" error very frequently (9 out of 10 tries).

i can't figure out why is that:(

here is the code

```
Public Shared Sub SetWindowTexboxText(WindowHandle As Integer, ObjectID As String, ObjectName As String, Value As String)
    Dim baseElement As AutomationElement
    baseElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(New System.IntPtr(WindowHandle))
    Dim oCurPattern As Object
    For Each oElement As AutomationElement In baseElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, ObjectID))
        If oElement.Current.Name = ObjectName Then
            oCurPattern = Nothing
            If oElement.TryGetCurrentPattern(Windows.Automation.ValuePattern.Pattern, oCurPattern) = True Then
                CType(oCurPattern, System.Windows.Automation.ValuePattern).SetValue(Value) //error throws on this line
            End If

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

best regards

Comment: Are you sure it's this code that is timing out, and not in fact the application your automating?  What debugging have you done.  Any sort of logging you can investigate?

Comment: @Hursey, sir, i think yes.. because the code error window pin point to that line number..